# How can I create a user in Linux that has a home but cannot login?

Tags: linux, user-accounts

I want to create a `media` user that should have a home folder created. This folder will have media (movies and what not).

All users will be added to the `media` group so they have read access to `media` files. `media` will also be used to give permissions to `media` in some other places.

All the guides I find tell you how to create a system user without a home and no login, but I want with a home and no login.

Comment: See this answer on U&L SE: [*What's the difference between `/sbin/nologin` and `/bin/false`?*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/10867/108618) Can you take it from here?

Comment: What are you going to do with a username that can only be used in a handful of commands such as `chown`? Seems like you could get by with just a `media` group. Then manually create the directory `/home/media` with root as the owner (instead of the unnecessary `media` owner).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thank you. I will check that out.

Comment: @sawdust I will be using the `media` user for some other processes. So I do need a `media` user.